# Simple PHP script connected to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code and need some customizations. I need a line break after each mysql record and the capability for the webpage to load at the very bottom. Can this be possible? Thanks in advance. CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  http-equiv="content-type">
    <title> Food Orders </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$server_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$password = "mysqlpW";
$database_name = "menuDB12";

$connection = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $password, $database_name);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Error: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

$attributes "SELECT tablenumber, food FROM clients";
$results = $connection->query($attributes);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "Table Number: " . $rows["tablenumber"]. " Food Item: " . $rows ["food"].
         "<br>";
            }
    } else {
        echo "No Results";
        }

$connection->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: line break in html is as easy as inserting `<br/>`.  I dont understand what you mean by loading the page at the bottom of the page at refresh.  Perhaps edit your question so people like me might help you better.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right, you want to display your database results at the end of the page, for that you can try this

```
$table = '';   if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
while ($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
     $table .= "Table Number: " . $rows["tablenumber"]. " Food Item: " . $rows ["food"].
     "<br>";
        }
} else {
    $table = "No Results";
    }
```

and at the end of your page or where you want it to be displayed simply add

```
<?php echo $table; ?>
```

Comment: No, I want a page break between each record and also I want the HTML page to load at the very bottom of the page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You write about line breaks in the original question, but in the comments you specify **page** breaks (for printing). 
Also, I understand you want the content to be displayed at the bottom of the printed page.

If my understanding is correct (and it would help if you edited the question to be more precise), I'd suggest consulting the following:

[Page breaks for printing on php page](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/158124/page-breaks-for-printing-on-php-page)

It helped me some time ago when I was creating a web-based document for printing.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `echo "<br>";` for a new line.

And i would recommend ajax for refreshing
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: No, I want a page break between each record and also I want the HTML page to load at the very bottom of the page. Thanks in advance